# Performing load test with nginx degrades performance when increasing concurrency

Tags: nginx, apachebench

Performance test results with Apache Bench.

Performance degrades with increasing concurrency.

Project is here
https://github.com/ohs30359-nobuhara/nginx-php7-alpine

```
$ ab -n 50 -c 1 "127.0.0.1/sample.html"

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   0.111 seconds
Complete requests:      50
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      11700 bytes
HTML transferred:       550 bytes
Requests per second:    448.50 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2.230 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.230 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          102.49 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       1
Processing:     1    2   0.9      2       6
Waiting:        1    2   0.8      2       5
Total:          1    2   1.0      2       6

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      2
  66%      2
  75%      2
  80%      2
  90%      3
  95%      5
  98%      6
  99%      6
 100%      6 (longest request)


$ ab -n 50 -c 50 "127.0.0.1/sample.html"

Concurrency Level:      50
Time taken for tests:   0.034 seconds
Complete requests:      50
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      11700 bytes
HTML transferred:       550 bytes
Requests per second:    1480.56 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       33.771 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.675 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          338.33 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    4   2.1      4       8
Processing:     9   18   5.2     20      24
Waiting:        2   18   5.5     20      24
Total:          9   23   5.6     25      30

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     25
  66%     26
  75%     26
  80%     27
  90%     29
  95%     29
  98%     30
  99%     30
 100%     30 (longest request)
```

The HTML returned here only displays characters that do not contain js or css．

I don't think the load will drop much with this load,

so is there a problem with nginx settings?

Comment: I don't think its an nginx problem. given that you are running your concurrent test in the same machine which your nginx is also running which may result to a low results.

Comment: Thank you
As you pointed out was a server problem

I raised the target application to k8s and confirmed that the problem was solved

However, html went well but php doesn't  ...